# Titanium, display the value in XML from javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I need to get the textarea value from java script file. below is my code,

On click of button in index.xml, the control should go to getPrivacy_policy() and display the privacy page.

**Privacy.xml**

```
<Alloy>
    <Window id="privacyWin" title="Plan India" platform="android,ios">
        <View id="header">
              <Label id="title">Privacy Policy</Label>
        </View>

         <TextArea id="privacyID" suppressReturn="false"></TextArea>

    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

**index.js**

```
   function getPrivacy_policy()
    {
        var privacy_string = "some long text...";
        return privacy_string;
        var privacyPolicy = Alloy.createController('privacy').getView();
        privacyPolicy.open();
    }
```

How can display the `privacy_string` value in textarea which is located in privacy.xml?

Note that both (XML and Js) are different files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Alloy you can access the view elements by their ID, so you can do:

```
$.privacyID.value
```

which will return the text inside the TextArea

Comment: where should I write the above statement?

Comment: Inside getPrivacy_policy() method or outside the method?

Comment: $.privacy.value will give you the value of the textarea, do with it what you like, put it in the place that makes the most sense for your application where you need that value.

Comment: I tried inside method, but I'm getting the following error, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Comment: I'm correct in thinking that this is an Alloy project right?

Comment: Yes you are correct. How can I do it in Alloy project?

Comment: well normally that's the way.  Can you update our original answer with the full code from your privacy.xml and privacy.js files?

Comment: Yes @phil I have updated the question, Please suggest some way to get the value

Comment: ok you've changed the name of the id of the textARea to privacyID so you need to call $.privacyID.value instead